# Why I can't use matched variable instead of a variable value?

Tags: idris

Here is an example from [here](https://idris.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html). The code looks like that:

```
sum : (single : Bool) -> isSingleton single -> Nat
sum True x = x
sum False [] = 0
sum False (x :: xs) = x + sum False xs
```

I've tried to use `single` instead of `False` in the last line. But it fails. I think the problem is that the type of `sum single xs` is either `Nat` or `List Nat`, but `+` requires only `Nat` operands. But we are inside a clause where `single` equals `False` either way. Shouldn't Idris infer it? Why I can't use `single` here? Is there some reason for it?

Here is the error:

```
main.idr:14:23-41:
   |
14 | sum False (x :: xs) = x + (sum single xs)
   |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When checking right hand side of Main.sum with expected type
        Nat

When checking argument single to Main.sum:
        No such variable single
```

**Upd:**
It looks like that the problem here is that I can't directly access the variable from type definition. Then I've tried to use implicit arguments like that:

```
sum : (single : Bool) -> isSingleton single -> Nat
sum True x = x
sum False [] = 0
sum {single} False (x :: xs) = x + sum single xs
```

It doesn't help either. Maybe I'm using it wrong. Also I've tried the simplest possible variation like that:

```
sum : (single: Bool) -> isSingleton single -> Nat
sum s list = case s of 
    True => list
    False => case list of
        [] => 0
        (x::xs) => x + (sum s xs)
```

But it doesn't compile either:

```
   |
16 |         (x::xs) => x + (sum s xs)
   |                         ~~~~~~~~
When checking right hand side of Main.case block in case block in sum at main.idr:12:19 at main.idr:14:19-22 with expected type
        Nat

When checking an application of Main.sum:
        Type mismatch between
                List Nat (Type of xs)
        and
                isSingleton s (Expected type)
```

It looks a bit weird for me, because from one point Idris could prove many interesting and complex things, and from another such a simple thins is unavailable. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @joel I've added the error to the post.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that it can't infer the type of `single`, as `single` isn't in scope on the RHS. You could use a named pattern with `single` on the LHS

```
sum : (single : Bool) -> isSingleton single -> Nat
sum True x = x
sum False [] = 0
sum single@False (x :: xs) = x + sum single xs
```

I can't see a way to avoid the named pattern in this case and just use

```
sum single (x :: xs) = x + sum single xs
```

as Idris doesn't infer it's a `List Nat` without the `False`. I get

```
  |
8 | sum single (x :: xs) = x + sum single xs
  | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When checking left hand side of Main.sum:
When checking an application of Main.sum:
        Can't disambiguate since no name has a suitable type: 
                Prelude.List.::, Prelude.Stream.::
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know about a syntax like ```single@False```. Could you give me a link where I can read about it? Or maybe a name of this feature, so I will able to find some info about it? The only problem in this code is that I need to write ```single``` twice. It's a bit disappointing...

Comment: @ChessMax it's called a _named pattern_ (not a bind as I originally wrote), but I can't find a reference to it other than in [this book](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris)